# isset fatal error in 5.6 but fine in 7

Tags: php

This snippet of code causes a PHP fatal error in 5.6, but works fine in 7.0 and above. There is no documented change to `isset` that I could find stating that it works with arrays as constants.

```
<?php
class Test
{
    const A = [1];
}

echo isset(Test::A[0]);
```

Does anyone know of any documentation stating this was an actual change? Is it safe to use `isset` with arrays as constants?

PHP 5.6.30 error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Comment: use it as a ternary method; what you have now will always be considered as being set

Comment: Yes it's more that it causes a fatal error in 5.6 but there was no documented change stating this now works in PHP 7, but it does

Comment: I remember reading about this in a changelog, but the docs do seem to still list the old behavior _Warning
isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use the defined() function._ http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php#refsect1-function.isset-notes

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php   class-constant with array-values are only PHP7+ possible

Comment: ^^ That's a different error.  5.6 errors on isset with `Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions PHP 5.6 allows arrays as constants

Comment: constants array is PHP7.0 feature. Check here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php#refsect1-function.isset-notes also states: *"Note: Because this is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using [variable functions.](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)"* so that should also be taken into consideration.

Comment: This feels like it may be worth a bug report against the documentation. Typically changes like this are spelled out clearly in the language docs at php.net

Comment: @MubasharIqbal interesting, [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php) states arrays can be assigned to constants using the ```const``` keyword. The PHP 7 documentation refers to arrays as constants using ```define```

Comment: It was also changed in HHVM 3.19.0, before it yielded "Arrays are not allowed in class constant", now it results in 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset()` is a language construct and not a function, so perhaps this paragraph (from http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php) applies:

> PHP 7 now uses an abstract syntax tree when parsing source files. This
>   has permitted many improvements to the language which were previously
>   impossible due to limitations in the parser used in earlier versions
>   of PHP, but has resulted in the removal of a few special cases for
>   consistency reasons, which has resulted in backward compatibility
>   breaks.

Comment: Ah that's a nice point. I wonder what other things this new parser may have affected. I will mark your answer as correct as it seems the most plausible (and is the only answer!)